# Working Windows always running chkdsk on boot

Tags: windows, ssd, chkdsk

I have Windows installed on a SSD on a fairly decent machine.
Since 2 weeks or so, Windows is always running the verification disk tool (chkdsk) despite the computer being working fine and not having asked it to run the check.

I also checked the registry which is not set to run a chkdsk on boot.
I run the dirty bit query command telling me that my C: drive is dirty (the one with windows installed).

Is my SSD going to die or is it some malware ?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (03) SPCC M.2 PCIe SSD
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : SPCC M.2 PCIe SSD
        Firmware : ECFM13.1
   Serial Number : FB59079C0E2500514024
       Disk Size : 256,0 GB
     Buffer Size : Inconnu
    # of Sectors : 
   Rotation Rate : ---- (SSD)
       Interface : NVM Express
   Major Version : NVM Express 1.3
   Minor Version : 
   Transfer Mode : PCIe 3.0 x4 | PCIe 3.0 x4
  Power On Hours : 3051 heures
  Power On Count : 563 fois
      Host Reads : 8724 GB
     Host Writes : 9222 GB
     Temperature : 41 C (105 F)
   Health Status : Bon (96 %)
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., TRIM, VolatileWriteCache
       APM Level : ----
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : C:

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 000000000000 Avertissement critique
02 000000000138 Température composite
03 000000000064 Cellules de rechange disponibles
04 000000000005 Seuil de cellules de rechange disponibles
05 000000000004 Pourcentage utilisé
06 0000011732DD Unités de données lues
07 000001271E88 Unités de données écrites
08 0000105B90C1 Commandes de lecture de l'hôte
09 00000E5F2A1D Commandes d'écriture de l'hôte
0A 000000000368 Temps occupé du contrôleur
0B 000000000233 Cycles d'alimentation
0C 000000000BEB Heures de mise sous tension
0D 000000000032 Arrêts dangereux
0E 000000000000 Erreurs d'intégrité des médias et des données
0F 0000000004A8 Nombre d'entrées du journal d'informations sur les erreurs

-- IDENTIFY_DEVICE ---------------------------------------------------------
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
000: 1987 1987 4246 3935 3730 4339 4530 3532 3030 3135
010: 3034 3432 5053 4343 4D20 322E 5020 4943 2065 5353
020: 2044 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020
030: 2020 2020 4345 4D46 3331 312E A701 6479 0900 0001
040: 0300 0001 9680 0098 9680 0098 0200 0000 0002 0000
050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0017 0303
130: 0812 043E 0101 015C 0161 0064 0000 0000 0000 0000
140: 6000 9E65 003B 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 000A 0100
160: 0000 0001 0139 0157 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
210: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
220: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
230: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
240: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
250: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

-- SMART_NVME --------------------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 00 3A 01 64 05 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
020: ED 32 17 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
030: 9C 1E 27 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
040: CB 94 5B 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
050: 40 2C 5F 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
060: 68 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
070: 33 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
080: EB 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
090: 32 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0B0: A8 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for that, Some are:

## 1. Improper Shutdown

shut down your pc always from start menu, try disabling disabling fast startup. Open control panel>hardware and sound>power options>choose what power button do> then click change settings that are currently unavailable. Then uncheck fast startup. Use `chkntfs /x c:` to not check disk if improper shutdown

## 2. Malware attack

Malware attack can also be a reason. Install a antivirus and update it frequently. Remove unnecessary or unknown apps. Don't visit unknown websites.
Run a full-scan and boot-time scan in antivirus

**Still there are other reasons too, please comment if none of these worked**

*Can you also say that it checks on reboot or not?*